# How to move part vmdk files into a larger disk partition?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmdk

Using VMWare Workstation 10.

The vmdk files is exhaustting my "D:\" space, so i want to move part vmdk files into a larger disk partition(e.g. "C:\").
I tried to move some vmdk files into "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended" and modified the main .vmdk file like bellow:

```
# Extent description
RW 4192256 SPARSE "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended\Ubuntu 64 位-s001.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended\Ubuntu 64 位-s002.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended\Ubuntu 64 位-s003.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended\Ubuntu 64 位-s004.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "C:\Ubuntu-1-vmd-extended\Ubuntu 64 位-s005.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s006.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s007.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s008.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s009.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s010.vmdk"
RW 4192256 SPARSE "Ubuntu 64 位-s011.vmdk"...
```

But it doesn't work, can not start it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Use the symbolic link in windows 7.
[image]